# Unable to run the cucumber project as java application

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, cucumber

I have created a Cucumber project in Eclipse IDE and Maven Build which I am exporting as a `.jar` file. So I have declared a `main` method and I'm calling the feature file with `cucumber.api.cli.Main`.

My `main` method is as shown below:

```
public class NewMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Before caling PhantomJS");

        File f = new File("C:\\Test\\text.txt");
        if (f.exists())

            f.delete();
        f.createNewFile();

        Main.main(new String[] { "-g", "com.cucumber.testcases",
                "src/test/java/com/cucumber/Features/PolicyFeatures.feature" });

        System.out.println("after caling PhantomJS");
    }

}
```

- **Project structure:**

[image]

I created the `.jar` file by selecting all the project dependencies and on extracting the `.jar` file, I'm getting all the jar files along as shown here:

[image]

Now on running the `.jar` file, it enters the `main` method as I am able to create file, but it **does not run** the feature file.

Please let me know what changes needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Place your feature files in the same package or a subpackage as your runner class. Place your steps in the same package structure. This will allow you to simplify theis configuration:

```
Main.main(new String[] { "-g", "com.cucumber.testcases",
                "src/test/java/com/cucumber/Features/PolicyFeatures.feature" });
```

It is possible that you can remove it completely.

A better approach that I would use is to start from a working example and transform it into what you want. A working example is found here: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton

Starting from a small, but working example, is usually a lot easier that getting a complex example to work. This follows from [Gall's law](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2015/02/28/galls-law)